# Selenium ChromeDriver switchTo.frame(WebElement) does not switch to the input frame consistently

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I use a recursive method (details skipped) to go through all iframes inside a web page.

```
void recursive(ChromeDriver driver) {
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"); 

   for (WebElement element: elements) {
        driver.switchTo.frame(element); 
        recursive(driver);
        driver.switchTo.parentFrame(); 
   }
}
```

The problem is,

- For the same webpage, this recursive method results in a infinitely loop occasionally (which means it run successfully the other times)
- I noticed that when infinitely loop happens, it's because during one of the recursions, switchTo.frame() does not switch to the input frame element, but rather switch back to main page (as if we use switchto().defaultcontent()).

Anyone here experience something like this before?

Comment: Recursion would require a new driver for each level.  (and I wouldn't go down that road...)  You probably want to use a non-recursive method....

Comment: Thanks but same problem in an iterative version of this method.